# How do I do an iterated intersection?

Tags: math-mode

I want the index to appear under the intersection symbol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In display math mode:

```
\[
       \bigcap_{x}
\]
```

will create a larger-than-normal ⋂, with x underneath it. (For

inline math mode, use `\displaystyle` if you want it always underneath it.)

If you want the intersection sign to be regular-sized, then I'd load the `amsmath` package and use `\underset{x}{\cap}` or something like that.

If neither of these are what you want, then I'm afraid I didn't fully understand the question.

Comment: oh, I see -- i forgot to put displaystyle.  Thanks!

Comment: for inline math, you can also write `\bigcap\limits_x`, but the extra vertical space that requires could well mess up the typesetting of the paragraph. (You should avoid spreading lines apart unevenly, which is why inline math uses different rules about where to place limits.)